# std::copy from memory buffer to vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to copy binary data from a mem buffer to a vector.

Please let me know what is wrong with the folloowing attempts

each time I am getting vector size as 0

```
int AhaConnectAPI::unpackDataArray(uint8_t* src, vector<uint64_t> dest, uint32_t destvectorSize, int offset)
{

    cout<<"\nstd::copy";
    std::copy(src + offset, src + offset + sizeof(uint64_t) * length, back_inserter(dest));
    return length * 8;
}
```

or

```
int AhaConnectAPI::unpackDataArray(uint8_t* src, vector<uint64_t> dest, uint32_t destvectorSize, int offset)
{

    uint64_t element;

    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i<destvectorSize; i++)
    {
         offset = unpackData(src, element, offset);
         dest.push_back(element);
    }

    return dest.size() * sizeof(uint64_t);

}
```

Comment: ... you take the `vector` by value?

Comment: Suggestion: If you don't modify src, pass as pointer to const.

Answer (score 3):

In your first `unpackDataArray()`: your `src` is of type `uint8_t*` but you use `sizeof(uint64_t)` in `std::copy` and for `dest`, and `offset` is an `int`.  Try something like:

```
std::copy(static_cast<uint64_t*>(src) +
              static_cast<uint64_t>(offset),
          static_cast<uint64_t*>(src) +
              static_cast<uint64_t>(offset) + sizeof(uint64_t) * length,
          back_inserter(dest));
```

`offset` may need further adjustment.  Also `length` appears out of nowhere.

Comment: Are you sure this will compile?

Comment: Length refers to no of elements in the vector which is passed externally does that make sense..?

Comment: @MarshelAbraham Elements of `uint8_t` of `uint64_t`?

Comment: vector of uint64_t so yeah no of elements each of size uint64_t

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int AhaConnectAPI::unpackDataArray(uint8_t* src, vector<uint64_t>& dest, 
                                   uint32_t destvectorSize, int offset)
```

You need to pass `vector` by reference (note the **&**).